# Обособить запятыми или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"Представьте" иногда выступает в роли вводного слова, но оно может обособляться тире? Например, "И - представьте - он упал" Тут нужна пауза и до и после "представьте", а паузой же обычно выделяется тире. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире возможно.

Не вижу причин сомневаться. Хотя я бы все равно использовал запятые, они тоже прекрасно передают паузу. Тире нужны более для зрительного выделения, а в такой короткой фразе это будет излишним, если только автор не имеет в виду что-то уж очень для него важное.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые тоже обозначают паузу. Тире обозначает усиление интонации перед фразой. Тогда лучше так:

И - представьте, он упал.

Довольно часто перед вводными словами ставится тире.

Полно примеров с запятыми:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_626